# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I got this error when I view it.

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View(string)' and
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View(System.Web.Mvc.IView)'

Here's my controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Selling() {
 _table = new QuestionnaireSelling();
 var model = _table.Get(UserID: _userId);
 return View(model);
}
```

This is my model class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using Massive;

namespace ChurchRealty.Models
{
    public class QuestionnaireSelling : DynamicModel
    {
        public QuestionnaireSelling() : base("ChurchRealty", "QuestionnaireSelling", "ID") { }

    }
}
```

This is my view
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3037520/Selling.cshtml

I used Massive by rob conery

Comment: Show us the controller action code

Comment: I'm using massive 

`[HttpGet]`
`public ActionResult Selling() {`
` _table = new QuestionnaireSelling();`
` var model = _table.Get(UserID: _userId);`
` return View(model);`
`}`

Comment: Post the code in your question please.  It's not easy to ready when posting code in a comment.

Comment: sorry first time to post in here

Comment: It's still difficult to say what the issue is.  Just remember to post as much code as possible so that we can look at it.  Can you post some of your view code as well?  Can you show some code for the QuestionnaireSelling class as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not much info given in the question.  I have the following on my view:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.MyViewModel
```

Just make sure that when you return the model that it is of the same type, here where you have:

```
var model = _table.Get(UserID: _userId);
return View(model);
```

In my case it would be something like:

```
MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel
{
     Users = _table.Get(UserID: _userId);
};

return View(viewModel);
```

If you can give some more detailed code in your question then I can update my answer.